# Can't display stop watch using pyqt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, stopwatch

I'm building a pretty simple GUI but I can't manage to work out my stop watch.
I have two different files - one for the variables of the GUI, and the main that has all of the functions.
My goal is, that once the user press on "run" button, the timer will appear on the small text box, changing every second in the form of 'hh:mm:ss'.
What I did is basically gathering a little info and a few code lines that i thought would fit my script, but I think I got a few things wrong and it doesn't work (I tried to change up a few things, but I get a different error every time..)

These are my files:

The GUI file:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



 class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(895, 422)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


    self.timer=QtCore.QTimer(self.centralwidget)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
    self.timer.start(1000)
    self.showTime(MainWindow)

    ###txtoutput = big window for text###
    self.txtoutput = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
    self.txtoutput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 200, 471, 192))
    self.txtoutput.setObjectName("txtoutput")

    ###modeltype = droplist###
    self.modeltype = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
    self.modeltype.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 69, 22))
    self.modeltype.setObjectName("modeltype")
    self.modeltype.addItem("")
    self.modeltype.addItem("")
    self.modeltype.addItem("")

    ###seriallbl = label above input window###
    self.seriallbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.seriallbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 81, 16))
    self.seriallbl.setObjectName("seriallbl")

    ###getserialbtn = "Enter" button###
    self.getserialbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.getserialbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 75, 23))
    self.getserialbtn.setObjectName("getserialbtn")

    ###chuckrealeasebtn = "Chuck"/"Release" button###
    self.chuckrealeasebtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
    self.chuckrealeasebtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 75, 23))
    self.chuckrealeasebtn.setObjectName("chuckrealeasebtn")
    self.chuckrealeasebtn.setCheckable(True)

    ###runbtn = "Run" button###
    self.runbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.runbtn.setEnabled(False)
    self.runbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 70, 91, 61))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(28)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.runbtn.setFont(font)
    self.runbtn.setCheckable(False)
    self.runbtn.setObjectName("runbtn")

    ###serialinput = Text box for serial # input###
    self.serialinput = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.serialinput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 151, 31))
    self.serialinput.setObjectName("serialinput")

    ###stopbtn = "Stop" button###
    self.stopbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.stopbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 70, 91, 61))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(28)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.stopbtn.setFont(font)
    self.stopbtn.setObjectName("stopbtn")

    ###exitbtn = "Exit" button###
    self.exitbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.exitbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 370, 75, 23))
    self.exitbtn.setObjectName("exitbtn")
    self.timelbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.timelbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 140, 47, 13))
    self.timelbl.setObjectName("timelbl")

    ###timertxt = label above timer window###
    self.timertxt = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
    self.timertxt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 160, 141, 31))
    self.timertxt.setObjectName("timertxt")


    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.modeltype.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 1"))
    self.modeltype.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 2"))
    self.modeltype.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 3"))
    self.seriallbl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter serial #"))
    self.getserialbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))
    self.chuckrealeasebtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "chuck"))
    self.runbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
    self.stopbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
    self.exitbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
    self.timelbl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Timer"))
```

And my main:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from mainwin import Ui_MainWindow


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
   super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()

   self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   self.ui.setupUi(self)   

   self.ui.exitbtn.clicked.connect(self.exitclicked)      
   self.ui.getserialbtn.clicked.connect(self.serialentered)
   self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.clicked.connect(self.chuckclicked)
   self.ui.runbtn.clicked.connect(self.showTime)

###exitclicked = "Exit" button function###
def exitclicked(self):                                      
    self.close()


def showTime(self):
    time=self.ui.QTime.currentTime()
    text=self.ui.time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
    if(time.second()%2==0):
        text=text[:2]+ ' ' +text [3:]
    self.ui.txtoutput.append(text)


###chuckclicked = "Chuck"/"Release" button function###    
def chuckclicked(self):
    if self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.isChecked():
        mytext = self.ui.serialinput.toPlainText()
        self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setText("Release")
        self.ui.getserialbtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.runbtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.txtoutput.append(mytext+" - is chucked, Ready to run")
    else:
        self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setText("Chuck")
        self.ui.txtoutput.clear()
        self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.ui.getserialbtn.setEnabled(True)
        self.ui.runbtn.setEnabled(False)

###serialentered = function that checks if the serial # that was entered is found or not found in a certain list###    
def serialentered(self):
    serialnum = self.ui.serialinput.toPlainText()
    listnum=self.ui.modeltype.currentIndex()
    if (listnum==0):
        with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 1.txt') as r1:
            if serialnum in r1.read():
                self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 1")
                self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
            else:
                self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 1")
                self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
    elif (listnum==1):
        with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 2.txt') as r2:
            if serialnum in r2.read():
                self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 2")
                self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
            else:
                self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 2")
                self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
    elif (listnum==2):
        with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 3.txt') as r3:
            if serialnum in r3.read():
                self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 3")
                self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
            else:
                 self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 3")
                 self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)



 def main():
  import sys
  app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
  application = ApplicationWindow()
  application.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()
```

So I'm not sure exactly what's wrong here - would love if someone has any ideas that I didn't manage to come up with..

Thanks in advance guys!

***I should edit that I want the stopwatch to start from 00:00:00 and count up every second after I hit "run" button"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never modify a module created in QT Designer.
Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


# from mainwin import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(895, 422)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


# -       self.timer=QtCore.QTimer(self.centralwidget)
# -       self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
# -       self.timer.start(1000)
# -       self.showTime(MainWindow)

        ###txtoutput = big window for text###
        self.txtoutput = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtoutput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 200, 471, 192))
        self.txtoutput.setObjectName("txtoutput")

        ###modeltype = droplist###
        self.modeltype = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.modeltype.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 69, 22))
        self.modeltype.setObjectName("modeltype")
        self.modeltype.addItem("")
        self.modeltype.addItem("")
        self.modeltype.addItem("")

        ###seriallbl = label above input window###
        self.seriallbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.seriallbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 81, 16))
        self.seriallbl.setObjectName("seriallbl")

        ###getserialbtn = "Enter" button###
        self.getserialbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.getserialbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 75, 23))
        self.getserialbtn.setObjectName("getserialbtn")

        ###chuckrealeasebtn = "Chuck"/"Release" button###
        self.chuckrealeasebtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 75, 23))
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setObjectName("chuckrealeasebtn")
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setCheckable(True)

        ###runbtn = "Run" button###
        self.runbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
# -       self.runbtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.runbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 70, 91, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.runbtn.setFont(font)
        self.runbtn.setCheckable(False)
        self.runbtn.setObjectName("runbtn")

        ###serialinput = Text box for serial # input###
        self.serialinput = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.serialinput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 151, 31))
        self.serialinput.setObjectName("serialinput")

        ###stopbtn = "Stop" button###
        self.stopbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stopbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 70, 91, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.stopbtn.setFont(font)
        self.stopbtn.setObjectName("stopbtn")

        ###exitbtn = "Exit" button###
        self.exitbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exitbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 370, 75, 23))
        self.exitbtn.setObjectName("exitbtn")
        self.timelbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.timelbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 140, 47, 13))
        self.timelbl.setObjectName("timelbl")

        ###timertxt = label above timer window###
        self.timertxt = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.timertxt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 160, 141, 31))
        self.timertxt.setObjectName("timertxt")


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.modeltype.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 1"))
        self.modeltype.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 2"))
        self.modeltype.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 3"))
        self.seriallbl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter serial #"))
        self.getserialbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "chuck"))
        self.runbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.stopbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        self.exitbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.timelbl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Timer"))


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)   

        self.ui.exitbtn.clicked.connect(self.exitclicked)      
        self.ui.getserialbtn.clicked.connect(self.serialentered)
        self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.clicked.connect(self.chuckclicked)
        self.ui.runbtn.clicked.connect(self.onClick_runbtn)         # - (self.showTime)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)                            # +++
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)                   # +++

    ###exitclicked = "Exit" button function###
    def exitclicked(self):                                      
        self.close()

    def onClick_runbtn(self):                                       # +++
        self.timer.start(1000)                                      # +++

    def showTime(self):
        time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()                           # - self.ui.QTime.currentTime()
        text = time.toString('hh:mm:ss')                            # - self.ui.time.toString('hh:mm:ss')
        if(time.second()%2==0):
            text = text[:2]+ ' ' +text [3:]
#        self.ui.txtoutput.append(text)
        self.ui.timelbl.setText(text)

    ###chuckclicked = "Chuck"/"Release" button function###    
    def chuckclicked(self):
        if self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.isChecked():
            mytext = self.ui.serialinput.toPlainText()
            self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setText("Release")
            self.ui.getserialbtn.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.runbtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.ui.txtoutput.append(mytext+" - is chucked, Ready to run")
        else:
            self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setText("Chuck")
            self.ui.txtoutput.clear()
            self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.getserialbtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.ui.runbtn.setEnabled(False)

    ###serialentered = function that checks if the serial # that was entered is found or not found in a certain list###    
    def serialentered(self):
        serialnum = self.ui.serialinput.toPlainText()
        listnum=self.ui.modeltype.currentIndex()
        if (listnum==0):
            with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 1.txt') as r1:
                if serialnum in r1.read():
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 1")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
                else:
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 1")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
        elif (listnum==1):
            with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 2.txt') as r2:
                if serialnum in r2.read():
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 2")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
                else:
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 2")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
        elif (listnum==2):
            with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 3.txt') as r3:
                if serialnum in r3.read():
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 3")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
                else:
                     self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 3")
                     self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApplicationWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

> why shouldnt I never edit a module created in QT designer?

Think for yourself what will happen if you want to change your design. You will remember for a long time what changes you will need to make ...

> I want my stopwatch to start from 0, and count up every second. Is there a way to do that or I can only show current time?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time                                                            # +++

# from mainwin import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(895, 422)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        ###txtoutput = big window for text###
        self.txtoutput = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.txtoutput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 200, 471, 192))
        self.txtoutput.setObjectName("txtoutput")
        ###modeltype = droplist###
        self.modeltype = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.modeltype.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 90, 69, 22))
        self.modeltype.setObjectName("modeltype")
        self.modeltype.addItem("")
        self.modeltype.addItem("")
        self.modeltype.addItem("")
        ###seriallbl = label above input window###
        self.seriallbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.seriallbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 81, 16))
        self.seriallbl.setObjectName("seriallbl")
        ###getserialbtn = "Enter" button###
        self.getserialbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.getserialbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 75, 23))
        self.getserialbtn.setObjectName("getserialbtn")
        ###chuckrealeasebtn = "Chuck"/"Release" button###
        self.chuckrealeasebtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 75, 23))
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setObjectName("chuckrealeasebtn")
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setCheckable(True)
        ###runbtn = "Run" button###
        self.runbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
# -       self.runbtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.runbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(580, 70, 91, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.runbtn.setFont(font)
        self.runbtn.setCheckable(False)
        self.runbtn.setObjectName("runbtn")
        ###serialinput = Text box for serial # input###
        self.serialinput = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.serialinput.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 50, 151, 31))
        self.serialinput.setObjectName("serialinput")
        ###stopbtn = "Stop" button###
        self.stopbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stopbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(680, 70, 91, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.stopbtn.setFont(font)
        self.stopbtn.setObjectName("stopbtn")
        ###exitbtn = "Exit" button###
        self.exitbtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exitbtn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(740, 370, 75, 23))
        self.exitbtn.setObjectName("exitbtn")
        self.timelbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.timelbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 140, 147, 23))         # +
        self.timelbl.setObjectName("timelbl")
        ###timertxt = label above timer window###
        self.timertxt = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
        self.timertxt.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 160, 141, 31))
        self.timertxt.setObjectName("timertxt")

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.modeltype.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 1"))
        self.modeltype.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 2"))
        self.modeltype.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Type 3"))
        self.seriallbl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter serial #"))
        self.getserialbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter"))
        self.chuckrealeasebtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "chuck"))
        self.runbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.stopbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop"))
        self.exitbtn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit"))
        self.timelbl.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Timer"))


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ApplicationWindow, self).__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)   

        self.ui.exitbtn.clicked.connect(self.exitclicked)      
        self.ui.getserialbtn.clicked.connect(self.serialentered)
        self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.clicked.connect(self.chuckclicked)
        self.ui.runbtn.clicked.connect(self.onClick_runbtn)            # + self.onClick_runbtn 

### VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)                            
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)                   
        self.time = 0
        self.timeInterval = 1000

    def onClick_runbtn(self):                                       
        self.timer.start(self.timeInterval)                                      
        self.timeViewer = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self)
        self.timeViewer.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 80, 100, 45))
        self.timeViewer.show()

    def showTime(self):  
        self.time += 1
        self.settimer(self.time)
        ##print(self.time)

    def settimer(self, int):
        self.time = int
        self.timeViewer.display(self.time)
        if self.timeInterval == 1000:
            self.ui.timelbl.setText(time.strftime('%H hour %M minute %S second',time.gmtime(self.time)))

### ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       

    ###exitclicked = "Exit" button function###
    def exitclicked(self):                                      
        self.close()        

    ###chuckclicked = "Chuck"/"Release" button function###    
    def chuckclicked(self):
        if self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.isChecked():
            mytext = self.ui.serialinput.toPlainText()
            self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setText("Release")
            self.ui.getserialbtn.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.runbtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.ui.txtoutput.append(mytext+" - is chucked, Ready to run")
        else:
            self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setText("Chuck")
            self.ui.txtoutput.clear()
            self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
            self.ui.getserialbtn.setEnabled(True)
            self.ui.runbtn.setEnabled(False)

    ###serialentered = function that checks if the serial # that was entered is found or not found in a certain list###    
    def serialentered(self):
        serialnum = self.ui.serialinput.toPlainText()
        listnum=self.ui.modeltype.currentIndex()
        if (listnum==0):
            with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 1.txt') as r1:
                if serialnum in r1.read():
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 1")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
                else:
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 1")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
        elif (listnum==1):
            with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 2.txt') as r2:
                if serialnum in r2.read():
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 2")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
                else:
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 2")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)
        elif (listnum==2):
            with open(r'C:\Users\hv_lab\Documents\python tests\Serial Numbers - Type 3.txt') as r3:
                if serialnum in r3.read():
                    self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was found in List 3")
                    self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(True)
                else:
                     self.ui.txtoutput.append(serialnum+" - Serial was NOT found in List 3")
                     self.ui.chuckrealeasebtn.setEnabled(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = ApplicationWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Nick! first of all - thank you so much.
I got a few qestions: 
why shouldnt I *never* edit a module created in QT designer?
I edited that I want my stopwatch to start from 0, and count up every second. Is there a way to do that or I can only show current time?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey Nick, I'm sorry to still bother you about this:
I am now trying to make the stopwatch go 0 again once I hit STOP button, but basically the watch goes double the speed next time...

Comment: @Alon123   Make a new question, attach the latest version of the example. Write what you want to do and what you can’t do.